# Footer Always in the bottom, and container stretching with it?

Tags: html, css

Am trying to make my footer always in the bottom of my site, and the container stretch with it when there is no enough data to fill to fill the whole browsing site, and when data gets added to the menu or the information block the container will stretch with them moving the footer down.

HTML Code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>البوابة الإلكترونية للنظام الأكاديمي || جامعة نجران ||</title>
<link href="int_styles_en.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css"></style>
</head>

<body>  

<div id="main">

    <div id="header">
        <div id="header-content">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/en/logo.gif">
        </div>
        <div id="header-menu">
            <ul align="center" class="nav_ul">
                <li><a href="index_en.html" class="navegator1"><span style="opacity: 0;"></span></a></li>
                <li><img src="images/colore-chng.png"></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navegator3"><span style="opacity: 0;"></span></a></li>
                <li><img src="images/font-size-icn.png"></li>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="navegator5"><span style="opacity: 0;"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="text-size">
                <ul align="center" class="font-size">
                    <li><a href="#" class="font-size1"><span style="opacity: 0;"></span></a></li>
                    <li class="font-last"><a href="#" class="font-size2"><span style="opacity: 0;"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="Colore-change">
                <ul align="center" class="colore-butoons">
                    <li><a href="#" class="colore-butoons1"><span style="opacity: 0;"></span></a></li>
                    <li class="color-last"><a href="#" class="colore-butoons2"><span style="opacity: 0;"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="right-elements">
        <div id="main-menu">
            <div id="main-menu-title">
                <img src="images/en/main-menu-title.png">
            </div>
            <div id="menu-text">
                <ul>
                    <li>  
                        <a href=""><span id="menuForm:t10"><img src="images/en/arw.png" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;التقويم الجامعي</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>   
                        <a href=""><span id="menuForm:t12"><img src="images/en/arw.png" border="none" class="menu-text-first">&nbsp;&nbsp;المقررات المطروحة</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li> 
                        <a href=""><span id="menuForm:t14"><img src="images/en/arw.png" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;الخطط الدراسية</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>  
                        <a href=""><span id="menuForm:t10"><img src="images/en/arw.png" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;التقويم الجامعي</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>   
                        <a href=""><span id="menuForm:t12"><img src="images/en/arw.png" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;المقررات المطروحة</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li> 
                        <a href=""><span id="menuForm:t14"><img src="images/en/arw.png" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;الخطط الدراسية</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li> 
                        <a href=""><span id="menuForm:t14"><img src="images/en/arw.png" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;الخطط الدراسية</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li> 
                        <a href=""><span id="menuForm:t14"><img src="images/en/arw.png" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;الخطط الدراسية</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li> 
                        <a href=""><span id="menuForm:t14"><img src="images/en/arw.png" border="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;الخطط الدراسية</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="left-elements">
        <div id="content-block">
            <div id="content-title">
                <img src="images/en/news-title.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-content">
        <div id="footer-logo">
            <img src="images/en/footer-logo.png">
        </div>
        <div id="footer-text">
            <div id="copyrights">
                <img src="images/en/copyrights.png">
            </div>
            <div id="visits">
                <h6>Portal Visits: 246781</h6>
            </div>
            <div id="design">
                <h1>Designed And Developed By <a href="http://www.ats-ware.com">ATS-Ware.Com</a></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(images/egg_shell.png);
}


/* ----------> FONTS Ids Start <---------- */

h1
{
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;  
    font-size:10pt; 
    font-weight: normal;
}

h2
{
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    font-size:10pt; 
    direction:ltr;
}

h3 { 
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    font-weight:lighter; 
    font-size:11pt;
}

h4 {    
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bolder;  
    font-size:11pt;
}

h5 { 
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    font-weight:lighter;
    font-size:10pt;
}

h6 {    
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;  
    font-size:10pt;
}


/* ----------> FONTS Ids End <---------- */

/* ---------> Body Starts Here <--------- */


/* ---------> Body Ends Here <--------- */

/* ---------> Header Starts Here <--------- */

#header {
    width:100%;
    height:127px; 
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#e5e6e7 url('images/header_bg.gif') repeat-x; 
}

#header-content {
    width:1000px;
    height:127px; 
    margin:0 auto;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    height: 94px;
    width: 396px;
}


#header-menu {
    float: right;
    width: 379px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    padding-top: 26px;
    height: 72px;
}


.nav_ul {  
    width:500px;  
    margin:0 auto;  
    list-style-type:none;  
}  

.nav_ul li{
    margin-right:21px;
    float: left;
    display:block;
    height:62px;
}

.nav_ul li a {
    background:url('images/en/nav.png') no-repeat scroll top left;
    width:59px;
    display: block;
    height: 62px;
    position: relative;
}



.nav_ul li a.navegator1 {
    width:59px;
}

.nav_ul li a.navegator2 {
    width:59px;
    background-position:-80px 0px;
}

.nav_ul li a.navegator3 {
    width:59px;
    background-position: -155px 0px;
}

.nav_ul li a.navegator4 {
    width:59px;
    background-position:-238px 0px;
}

.nav_ul li a.navegator5 {
    width:59px;
    background-position:-316px 0px;
}


.nav_ul a span {
    background:url('images/en/nav.png') no-repeat scroll bottom left;
    display:block;
    top:0;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.nav_ul li a.navegator1 span {
    background-position:0px -73px;
}

.nav_ul li a.navegator2 span {
    background-position:-80px -73px;
}

.nav_ul li a.navegator3 span {
    background-position:-155px -73px;
}

.nav_ul li a.navegator4 span {
    background-position:-238px -73px;
}

.nav_ul li a.navegator5 span {
    background-position:-316px -73px;
}

#text-size {
    height: 0;
    padding-left: 244px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 73px;
}

.font-size {  
    width:56px;  
    margin:0 auto;  
    list-style-type:none;  
}  

.font-last {
    margin-left:17px;
}

.font-size li{
    float: left;
    display:block;
    height:11px;
}

.font-size li a {
    background:url('images/font-size.png') no-repeat scroll top left;
    width:15px;
    display: block;
    height: 11px;
    position: relative;
}

.font-size li a.font-size1 {
    width:15px;
}

.font-size li a.font-size2 {
    width:19px;
    background-position:-37px 0px;
}

.font-size a span {
    background:url('images/font-size.png') no-repeat scroll bottom left;
    display:block;
    top:0;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.font-size li a.font-size1 span {
    background-position:0px -14px;
}

.font-size li a.font-size2 span {
    background-position:-37px -14px;
}

#Colore-change {
    height: 0;
    padding-left: 82px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 72px;
}

.colore-butoons {  
    width:56px;  
    margin:0 auto;  
    list-style-type:none;  
}  

.color-last {
    margin-left:23px;
}

.colore-butoons li{
    float: left;
    display:block;
    height:11px;
}

.colore-butoons li a {
    background:url('images/colore-buttons.png') no-repeat scroll top left;
    width:16px;
    display: block;
    height: 18px;
    position: relative;
}

.colore-butoons li a.colore-butoons1 {
    width:16px;
}

.colore-butoons li a.colore-butoons2 {
    width:16px;
    background-position:-40px 0px;
}

.colore-butoons a span {
    background:url('images/colore-buttons.png') no-repeat scroll bottom left;
    display:block;
    top:0;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.colore-butoons li a.colore-butoons1 span {
    background-position:0px -18px;
}

.colore-butoons li a.colore-butoons2 span {
    background-position:-40px -18px;
}

/* ----------> Header Ends Here <---------- */


/* ---------> Contaner Starts Here <--------- */

#main {
    height:auto;    
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 450px;
    width: 1032px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    background: url('images/bg.png') repeat-y;
}


#right-elements {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 209px;
    float: left;
}

#main-menu {
    float: left;
    min-height:240px;
    height:100%;
    width:202px;
    background: #f5f5f5 url('images/block-head.png') repeat-x;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    border-radius: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #aca9b3;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #aca9b3;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #aca9b3;
}

#main-menu-title {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 137px;
    height: 23px;
    float: left;
}

#menu-text {
    float: left;
    direction: ltr;
    padding-top: 9px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#menu-text ul {
    list-style-type:none; 
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px;
}

#menu-text ul li { 
    line-height:1.9em;
    border-top:dashed 1px #c6c6c6; 
    padding:0px;
}

#menu-text ul li a {
    color: #0e3670;
    padding-left: 5px;
    display: block;
    font-size:10pt; 
    font-family:tahoma, arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu-text ul li a:hover {
    color:#ffffff;
    padding-right:5px;
    background:url('images/en/menu-hover.png') no-repeat top left #31b6e5; 
}

#menu-text ul li.menu-text-first {
    border-top:none;
}


#left-elements {
    float: right;
    width: 798px;
}

#content-block {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 774px;
    min-height: 240px;
    margin-right: 23px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #f5f5f5 url('images/block-head.png') repeat-x;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    border-radius: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #aca9b3;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #aca9b3;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #aca9b3;
}

#content-title {
    direction: ltr;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 33px;
    float: left;
}

#content_text {
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    float: left;
    direction: ltr;
}


/* ---------> Contaner Ends Here <--------- */

/* ---------> Fotter Stars Here <--------- */


#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #e5e6e7 url('images/footer-img.png') repeat-x; 
} 

#footer-content {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 90px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#footer-logo {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-top: 27px;
    height: 51px;
    width: 224px;
}

#footer-text {
    width: 333px;
    float: right;
}

#copyrights {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 7px;
    width: 333px;
    height: 17px;
    padding-top: 21px;
}

#visits {
    float: right;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-right: 7px;
}

#design {
    float: right;
    color:#b3b1b1;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-right: 7px;
}

#design a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* ---------> Fotter Ends Here <--------- */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<div class="header">
</div>
<div id="Content">
<div class="con"></div>
</div>
<div class="header">
</div>
```

Style

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body
    {
        height: 99%;
        background-color:Black;
    }
    .header
    {
        width: 960px;
        height: 15%;
        background-color:Gray;
    }
    #Content
    {
        min-height: 85%;
        width: 960px;
        background-color:Navy;
    }
    .con
    {
        min-height:900px;
        width:960px;
        background-color:Aqua;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: the values of the height must not be fixed, thay have to be 100% or auto so the container would stretch with its content!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to lock the footer at the bottom of the page:

```
 #footer{
 position: absolute;bottom: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: this only sends the footer to the bottom I already tried it before  but the container will only stretch with its content, not between the header and the footer!

Comment: I get what you mean than, I think that you need to use some javascript :S can you see if this is working for you? I'm not sure is the cleaner solution tho

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer{
position: fixed;
clear:both;
}
```

That is for placing the footer at the bottom in a fixed position that doesn't move when you scroll the webpage. I also noticed you use other divs inside the footer div. It is recommended not to nest too many divs when it's possible. I think 1 div for the footer is enough and for styling the other elements in the footer you should use classes.

Comment: unforinatly this didn't work, when i have less menu objects the footer still goes up with the container

Comment: okay, let me take a better look at the whole code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

The js code sounds like this, I'm not sure is the best solution:

```
<script type="text/css">
    function myFunction(){
    var height = window.innerHeight;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
$("body").css("min-height", window.innerHeight);
}
</script>


    <body onresize="myFunction()">
      <div id="main" >
         test
      </div>
    </body>
```

This script will resize your main div, every time the window is resized, i think filling the space and letting your footer where it is.

I forgot to add some edits that you need on your css, that are rhe height values of your content, and of your left content, you need to remove those, of your content will eixt the div.

Comment: am geting this error with chrome inspector:

Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined internal_ar.html:84
onresize

Comment: That because you should include the script tag in the header. Sry for the problem. I tested your code a little bit more, and i noticed that you have a fixed size fot a tag called #content-title.and one for a div called content-block. Can you please try to use the new css that i'll post?

Answer (score 0):

I think i misunderstood your problem, the js was not the right answer for what you want to achieve, can you try to use this css? Is very similar to yours besides 2 or 3 sections. You need to be more careful when you are using the attribute height, because that prevents the div to stretch.

```
<style type="text/css">
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(images/egg_shell.png);
}


/* ----------> FONTS Ids Start <---------- */

h1
{
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;  
    font-size:10pt; 
    font-weight: normal;
}

h2
{
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    font-size:10pt; 
    direction:ltr;
}

h3 { 
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    font-weight:lighter; 
    font-size:11pt;
}

h4 {    
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bolder;  
    font-size:11pt;
}

h5 { 
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    font-weight:lighter;
    font-size:10pt;
}

h6 {    
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;  
    font-size:10pt;
}


/* ----------> FONTS Ids End <---------- */

/* ---------> Body Starts Here <--------- */


/* ---------> Body Ends Here <--------- */

/* ---------> Header Starts Here <--------- */

#header {
    width:100%;
    height:127px; 
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#e5e6e7 url('images/header_bg.gif') repeat-x; 
}

#header-content {
    width:1000px;
    height:127px; 
    margin:0 auto;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    height: 94px;
    width: 396px;
}


#header-menu {
    float: right;
    width: 379px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    padding-top: 26px;
    height: 72px;
}


.nav_ul {  
    width:500px;  
    margin:0 auto;  
    list-style-type:none;  
}  

.nav_ul li{
    margin-right:21px;
    float: left;
    display:block;
    height:62px;
}

.nav_ul li a {
    background:url('images/en/nav.png') no-repeat scroll top left;
    width:59px;
    display: block;
    height: 62px;
    position: relative;
}



.nav_ul li a.navegator1 {
    width:59px;
}

.nav_ul li a.navegator2 {
    width:59px;
    background-position:-80px 0px;
}

.nav_ul li a.navegator3 {
    width:59px;
    background-position: -155px 0px;
}

.nav_ul li a.navegator4 {
    width:59px;
    background-position:-238px 0px;
}

.nav_ul li a.navegator5 {
    width:59px;
    background-position:-316px 0px;
}


.nav_ul a span {
    background:url('images/en/nav.png') no-repeat scroll bottom left;
    display:block;
    top:0;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.nav_ul li a.navegator1 span {
    background-position:0px -73px;
}

.nav_ul li a.navegator2 span {
    background-position:-80px -73px;
}

.nav_ul li a.navegator3 span {
    background-position:-155px -73px;
}

.nav_ul li a.navegator4 span {
    background-position:-238px -73px;
}

.nav_ul li a.navegator5 span {
    background-position:-316px -73px;
}

#text-size {
    height: 0;
    padding-left: 244px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 73px;
}

.font-size {  
    width:56px;  
    margin:0 auto;  
    list-style-type:none;  
}  

.font-last {
    margin-left:17px;
}

.font-size li{
    float: left;
    display:block;
    height:11px;
}

.font-size li a {
    background:url('images/font-size.png') no-repeat scroll top left;
    width:15px;
    display: block;
    height: 11px;
    position: relative;
}

.font-size li a.font-size1 {
    width:15px;
}

.font-size li a.font-size2 {
    width:19px;
    background-position:-37px 0px;
}

.font-size a span {
    background:url('images/font-size.png') no-repeat scroll bottom left;
    display:block;
    top:0;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.font-size li a.font-size1 span {
    background-position:0px -14px;
}

.font-size li a.font-size2 span {
    background-position:-37px -14px;
}

#Colore-change {
    height: 0;
    padding-left: 82px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 72px;
}

.colore-butoons {  
    width:56px;  
    margin:0 auto;  
    list-style-type:none;  
}  

.color-last {
    margin-left:23px;
}

.colore-butoons li{
    float: left;
    display:block;
    height:11px;
}

.colore-butoons li a {
    background:url('images/colore-buttons.png') no-repeat scroll top left;
    width:16px;
    display: block;
    height: 18px;
    position: relative;
}

.colore-butoons li a.colore-butoons1 {
    width:16px;
}

.colore-butoons li a.colore-butoons2 {
    width:16px;
    background-position:-40px 0px;
}

.colore-butoons a span {
    background:url('images/colore-buttons.png') no-repeat scroll bottom left;
    display:block;
    top:0;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.colore-butoons li a.colore-butoons1 span {
    background-position:0px -18px;
}

.colore-butoons li a.colore-butoons2 span {
    background-position:-40px -18px;
}

/* ----------> Header Ends Here <---------- */


/* ---------> Contaner Starts Here <--------- */

#main {
    height:auto;    
}

#container {
    min-height: 20%;
    //height:60%;
    width: 1032px;
    margin: 0 auto 400px auto;
    background-color: white;
    background: url('images/bg.png') repeat-y;
}


#right-elements {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 209px;
    float: left;
}

#main-menu {
    float: left;
    min-height:240px;
    height:100%;
    width:202px;
    background: #f5f5f5 url('images/block-head.png') repeat-x;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    border-radius: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #aca9b3;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #aca9b3;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #aca9b3;
}

#main-menu-title {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 137px;
    height: 23px;
    float: left;
}

#menu-text {
    float: left;
    direction: ltr;
    padding-top: 9px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#menu-text ul {
    list-style-type:none; 
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px;
}

#menu-text ul li { 
    line-height:1.9em;
    border-top:dashed 1px #c6c6c6; 
    padding:0px;
}

#menu-text ul li a {
    color: #0e3670;
    padding-left: 5px;
    display: block;
    font-size:10pt; 
    font-family:tahoma, arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu-text ul li a:hover {
    color:#ffffff;
    padding-right:5px;
    background:url('images/en/menu-hover.png') no-repeat top left #31b6e5; 
}

#menu-text ul li.menu-text-first {
    border-top:none;
}


#left-elements {
    float: right;
    --width: 798px;
}

#content-block {
    float: right;
    min-height:60%;
    --height: 100%;
    width: 774px;
    min-height: 240px;
    margin-right: 23px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #f5f5f5 url('images/block-head.png') repeat-x;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    border-radius: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #aca9b3;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #aca9b3;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #aca9b3;
}

#content-title {
    direction: ltr;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 700px;
    --height: 33px;
    float: left;
}

#content_text {
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    float: left;
    direction: ltr;
}


/* ---------> Contaner Ends Here <--------- */

/* ---------> Fotter Stars Here <--------- */


#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #e5e6e7 url('images/footer-img.png') repeat-x; 
    position:fixed;bottom:0;right:0;
} 

#footer-content {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 90px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#footer-logo {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-top: 27px;
    height: 51px;
    width: 224px;
}

#footer-text {
    width: 333px;
    float: right;
}

#copyrights {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 7px;
    width: 333px;
    height: 17px;
    padding-top: 21px;
}

#visits {
    float: right;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-right: 7px;
}

#design {
    float: right;
    color:#b3b1b1;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-right: 7px;
}

#design a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* ---------> Fotter Ends Here <--------- */


</style>
```

Comment: thanx for the effort, but the container dev is still not stretching to fill the space between (it only  stretching to the height of the tallest of the inside content of the dev) the header and the footer! and adding more <li>'s to the menu is making it disappear behind the footer!